# Identify the counts of each distinct value in one column in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to identify the count of each distinct value in one column (`name`) in a table called `brgy`.

```
---------------------
| ID  |  name        |
---------------------    
| 1   |   Alfonso    |
| 2   |   Arakan     |
| 3   |   Poblacion  |
| 4   |   Ilaya      |
| 5   |   Poblacion  |
----------------------
```

I tried using this code but it keeps giving the `COUNT` as `1` despite `Poblacion` appearing twice in the `name` column:

```
SELECT name,COUNT(name) AS distinct_name
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT name
  FROM brgy
  GROUP BY name
)
GROUP BY name;
```

The intended output should eliminate duplicate `name`s but sum up the number of times the distinct `name` appears in the `name` column:

Expected Output is as below,

```
-----------------------------
| name      | distinct_name |
-----------------------------  
| Alfonso   |    1          |
| Arakan    |    1          |
| Ilaya     |    1          |
| Poblacion |    2          |
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `GROUP BY name`:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS distinct_name
FROM brgy
GROUP BY name;
```

you don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM brgy GROUP BY name
```

because `GROUP BY name` takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the subquery because it will give you unique entry  :

```
select name, count(*) as distinct_name
from brgy 
group by name
order by distinct_name, name;
```